# Is it possible to interact with Nant builds progmatically?

Tags: .net, build, nant

My reflector trial has just ran out :( so I cannot really check the assembly at the moment, so I was wondering if there is any way to interact with nant files progmatically from .net.

I basically want to be able to do the following progmatically:

- See all build tasks
- Run a build task
- Read the output of the task (ideally in some model, but in a string would be acceptable I guess)

I am sure Nant can do this internally when you run it though the command line but was wondering if anyone could give me a quick snippet of how to do this within .net (if it is possible)

Answer (score 0):

Check out NAntMenu; it's an open source utility written in c# code.
http://nantmenu.codeplex.com/
NAntMenu.Core.dll contains code to parse a nant file, enumerating all build targets, and execute a target.  When executing, it uses NAntMenu.Logger.dll to log the output.